# How can one greate grid/tile view of selected parts of windows on xfce/linux

Tags: linux, desktop, xfce

I have a few windows on my linux machine using the xfce4 desktop enviorment.

I wish to have a grid-like view where i can see only the part of each window im intrested in.

An example for the general vision:

- see a script running without the window borders on terminal across the header
- see work status of F@H client out of the advenced client view in the middle left
- see only the turrents status list of qBittorrent at middle right
- have another terminal at footer (again without header/borders)

My best way to describe it shortly is to generate a view from selective parts of windows.

Added a picture for illustration

Is there any way of doing such thing in a practical way? Am i missing out on a great software?

[image]

Comment: What you want is tiling window manager, which Xfce isn't. Take a look at i3 or sway.

Comment: Would a tiling window manager allow me to crop selective parts out of a window? will i lose my ability to drag windows around which i really love?

Comment: They are meant to always show the whole contents of windows and never waste screen space, some support floating windows. You should find out by yourself if they are fit to your workflow. By the way, these kind of questions are more appropriate for [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: thank for for you comment, i will try my luck at Super User as well. and look a bit more into tileing window managers.

Answer (score 0):

There are several tiling helpers for Xfce.
Perhaps try [xpytile](https://github.com/jaywilkas/xpytile/) , which is a tiling add-on for Xfce. It offers
automatic tiling, manual tiling and can simulaneously resize side-by-side windows (like AeroSnap for MS-Windows).